# Split given numbers into groups satisfying some constraints

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

Lets say I am given list of $n$ real numbers: $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$. Some of them might be repeating, so lets assume in this list there are $k$ distinct numbers: $\{a_1^{m_1},a_2^{m_2},\ldots,a_k^{m_k}\}$, where $m_1+m_2+\cdots+m_k=n$.

Definition (Log Majorization): Denote  $x=[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]$ and $y=[y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n]$, such that $x_1\geq x_2\geq\cdots\geq x_n$ and $y_1\geq y_2\geq\cdots\geq y_n$. Then $x \prec_{\mathrm{log}}y$, if $\prod_{i=1}^k x\leq \prod_{i=1}^k y$ and $\prod_{i=1}^n x= \prod_{i=1}^n y$. The meaning of log majorization is that $x$ is more even than $y$.

I want to split $\{a_1^{m_1},a_2^{m_2},\ldots,a_k^{m_k}\}$ into the groups satisfying these constraints:

1. There must be no repeating number in the same group,
2. Number of groups is equal to the $\begin{array}{ll} \underset{i=1,2,\cdots,k}{\text{max}} & m_i\end{array}$,
3. Make product in each group as even as possible.

Example: For $\{2^2,3,5,7\}$ we have $\begin{array}{ll} \underset{i=1,2,\cdots,k}{\text{max}} & m_i\end{array}=2$, so we need to split in two groups. The following options are availabe:

Option 1: $\{2,3,5,7\}$ and $\{2\}$, where we have two products $210$ and $2$.
Option 2: $\{2,5,7\}$ and $\{2,3\}$, where we have two products $70$ and $6$.
Option 3: $\{2,3,7\}$ and $\{2,5\}$, where we have two products $42$ and $10$.
Option 4: $\{2,3,5\}$ and $\{2,7\}$, where we have two products $30$ and $14$.

We need to choose Option 4 because $[30\quad 14]\prec_{\mathrm{log}}[42\quad 10]\prec_{\mathrm{log}}[70\quad 6]\prec_{\mathrm{log}}[210\quad 2]$.

I am trying to find right algorithm to do it. First step is easy, we just take the most repeating number and put one of these numbers to each group. Now each group has one equal number and second constraint is satisfied. Next step is not clear, shell I continue with the next most repeating number? And the third constraint giving the most problem.

Comment: What does the third condition mean?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin after we split into groups, we calculate the product in each group. For Example 2, there are four ways we can split into two groups: $\{2,3,5,7\}$ and $\{2\}$, $\{2,3,7\}$ and $\{2,5\}$, $\{2,5,7\}$ and $\{2,3\}$,  $\{2,3,5\}$ and $\{2,7\}$. We can to choose the last way, since the products are $30$ and $14$, is more even than in the first way $210$ and $2$, or second way $42$ and $10$, or third way $70$ and $6$.

Comment: But if you have ten groups, what does this condition mean, in a precise mathematical way?

Comment: You should definitely include this nontrivial definition in your question!

Comment: @J.-E.Pin done!

Comment: How fast should the algorithm be, in terms of $n$, or else in terms of $k$ and $\max m_i$?

Comment: @CTVK I just want to know, what is the most straightforward way to split in the groups, not necessarily fastest way.